# change the color of class active in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

i'm trying to change the color of class active in my html code. i'm creating nav sidebar. here's my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-static"> <!--stacked untuk jadi vertical -->
                    <li class="active"><a>Create Case</a></li>
                    <li><a href="wf-listofcase.php">List of cases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="linksofapps.html">Links of Apps</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
```

how to change its color? thanks before..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

```
.active a{
    color: red !important;
}
```

Or to avoid `!important`, use:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a{
    color: red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/m7ovq2km/)

Answer (score 5):

The following code applies red color for all the anchor tags.

```
a {
   color: red !important;
  }
```

To apply the color only within the "nav-static" wrapper, use the following code.

```
.nav-static .active a{
   color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above answers don't work try out -

```
.active a{
    background-color : red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for each a tag element add this

```
<a onclick="addHighlightedClass(event)"
```

then add this script to your page

```
  <script>
          function addHighlightedClass(event) {
            var target = event.currentTarget;
            if (window.previewHighlited)
              window.previewHighlited.classList.remove("active");
        
            target.classList.add("active");
            window.previewHighlited = target;
          }
  </script>
```

here is a demo
https://jsfiddle.net/bilalmix12/vkouxb7a/3/